# Factory Design Pattern VS Constructor

Tags: oop, design-patterns, constructor, factory, factory-pattern

I have a Product class that contains methods and a complex data structure. I will have 8 types of products that differ only in the contents of the data structure, nothing else. In my application I will then need to create one instance of each of the 8 types of product, once, and the types of products that exist do not change at run-time.

What is the best approach and why?

A) Class Product has 8 sub-classes. Each of these sub-classes defines only the constructor. Inside each constructor the data structure is properly created for that type of product.

B) A Factory class has 8 sub-classes. Each of these sub-classes is a concrete factory for each of the 8 types of products. Class Product has no sub-classes. Each concrete factory creates the specific type of product by creating the appropriate data structure and passing it as an argument to the constructor of class Product.

I have been reviewing the advantages of the Factory design pattern and I can't see, for this specific case, any of those advantages in B over A. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've never seen a factory be subclassed. It would have methods for each type. If you want a static set of Product objects, though, a Factory is more for creating those at runtime

Comment: You mean like a Factory with a method that returns a set with the 8 products? Is it considered correct Factory design pattern if it returns a set instead of a single object?

Comment: "I will have 8 types of products that differ only in the contents of the data structure, nothing else." What is the data structure? If it's just an aggregate (e.g., Array, LinkedList, etc.), then you don't need 8 sub-classes.

Comment: It is some sort of Collection of objects of another class. So without product sub-classes, are you suggesting option B? Or what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a variation of A, plus perhaps a factory class.  A factory is meant to create classes with methods defined in an interface class, such that the consumer of the factory-created object doesn't know what type of object they are dealing with, but only the interface.  The factory itself knows what type of object to create.

If there is a certain type of logic for what type of Product to create at a given time, implement a factory for 8 Products that implement an IProduct interface, and implement the logic for what type of product to create inside the factory.

Comment: I'm trying to fully understand your suggestion: So how would you have the application specify to the factory the type of product it requires? By passing some sort of argument? If so, why is it advantageous that the application doesn't know the product sub-classes when, instead, it has to know the types of arguments to pass to the factory... isn't it the same?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you pass a parameter to the Factory, but I don't know in your case what kind of parameter that would be. For example, I have a Factory pattern in one instance that provides XML parsing for various types of feeds and just gives you the root messages.  It could be an Atom Feed or a SOAP web service, but the factory takes the URL and simply knows what type of parser to give you based on what URL it is.

Comment: Could be the name of the product, for example.  Or its barcode. It's just a better practice to program to interfaces instead of specific types of objects.

Comment: I see. So let's imagine in my case i would pass the name of the product. But if the application needs to know the product name, isn't that as bad as having to know the names of the concrete product sub-classes? Later if i add another sub-class i have to add another name...

Comment: And another question, if instead of interface for Product i would use an abstract class with some methods already defined, is that bad practice?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with that.  Often, you'll see an interface definition, and an abstract base class with some methods having base implementations, and plenty of inherited classes from that base class implementing said interface.

Comment: I meant abstract base class INSTEAD of the interface, is this bad? And about the other question, i just can't understand why having to know product names is preferred to having to know sub-class names...

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Factory design pattern you can create objects of different subclasses from a single factory. See following example-

[image]

According to me using subclass approach with the factory design pattern would be a better option for the mentioned scenario.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your answer is suggesting the same as @kevin-hirst 's answer. So my question is: how will the factory know what product to create? If we have to pass it some sort of product "name" then it means the application must know the product names. Isn't this as bad as knowing the product subclasses?

Comment: While creating a new object of a class through factory I believe you need to know the name or any distinctive feature of the class you want to build. Otherwise how can you create the object of specific class? There is no way the factory will know it on it's own.
Once the object is created factory will return the specific object with parent class reference. This step afterwards system doesn't need to know about subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned - *I will have 8 types of products that differ only in the contents of the data structure, nothing else...*. That means state and methods are same with different contents. Based on that I feel this is clear indication that these are not subclasses but instances of same class. I think the code will contain only one product class and 8 instances of those. Factory is absolutely not required it will be unnecessary code.

Comment: Yes you are right, it makes more sense to have 8 instances, not 8 subclasses. But the problem is that the creation of the 8 different data structures is complex and i don't want the client application to have to know how to do it. So the construction logic can be in one of two places: either in a factory (option B of my post) or in the constructor of Product (in which case would require 8 different constructors, which leads to the 8 subclasses, i.e., option A of my post).

Comment: The builder pattern could be useful in that case, @CesarPim. It doesn't require subclasses. Composite pattern could also apply, if your data structure has composites (and methods that apply accordingly). You should update your question to specify the details of your 8 data structures.